# What to do when you find out your research result is wrong because it's based on wrong methods/results, after years of works?

Tags: research-process, errors-erratum, negative-results

This is not my current situation. However I've heard similar stories from different people (along with my own past experience) a few times. Therefore I want to ask a general question(the title).

For example, suppose you're a graduate student in one of the following scenarios

1. You believe you prove a theorem but later find out it's wrong because one of the lemma/theorem you cite from another published paper is wrong.
2. You spend long time setting up experiments and finding out an published experiment result is not reproducible and is likely to be wrong.
3. You rely on co-workers' code to run simulations but it turns out that there are errors in the code that makes the simulation inaccurate, therefore the conclusion based on that is wrong.

and let's further assume you find out those problems when it's closed to advancement or dissertation time of graduate study. You've spent a few years, only to get a faulty result that is not likely to advance you to the next stage of a researcher.

Q. Are these scenarios hopeless (i.e. a student in that scenario must terminate graduate study)? Should the student be the only one responsible for the issue?

If not, what's the best thing one can do in those scenarios?

If so, how to prevent them? (You can still answer this question even if your answer to Q. is no.)

Highly appreciated if anyone can discuss this from either student's or advisor's point of view.

Comment: See [What to do when you spend several months working on an idea that fails in a masters thesis?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/30995/what-to-do-when-you-spend-several-months-working-on-an-idea-that-fails-in-a-mast), [What to do when research leads to poor results?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/47692/what-to-do-when-research-leads-to-poor-results), [How to overcome discouragement on finding major error in work just before paper submission?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55479/11365)

Comment: Also [Is a research thesis (report) with zero contribution to human knowledge acceptable?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12502/is-a-research-thesis-report-with-zero-contribution-to-human-knowledge-acceptab) and [What to do with negative research outcomes (results) of PhD research experiment?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7421/what-to-do-with-negative-research-outcomes-results-of-phd-research-experiment)

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the [tag:negative-results] and [tag:errors-erratum] tags. Browsing previous questions with these tags might be useful.

Comment: Should the student be the only one responsible for the issue? Yes, because it is his PhD. He should have cross-checked multiple times the previous works he bases his work on.  Should a student in that scenario must terminate graduate study? No, but he should expect to spend another 2-4 years in this PhD to produce something meaningful and publishable. If even after this additional time he does not produce anything worthwhile, then he does not deserve a PhD.

Comment: @Alexandros well if your conclusion is "spend another 2-4 years" in many places it means "leave the program immediately" because the department has time limit on when a student should advance/graduate.

Comment: Usually PhD programs may be extended easily for 2 years more.

Comment: @Alexandros, in the U.S., in math, it is highly non-trivial to get funding (e.g., as TA + tuition) for two more years. Yes, often one can get put into a status that one does not have to pay tuition, and is still "in the program", but... not funded. For one thing, there are too many people competing for the 5-6 years of funding to let people stretch it out to 8.

Comment: @paulgarrett I never said anything about funding. If the OP has spent 5-6 years to discover that his research was based on wrong assumptions and is meaningless, then he does not deserve a PhD. If he can come up with something publishable and worthwhile in the next 2 years (funded or not) he might get his PhD. You cannot grant someone a PhD just because he tried.

Comment: @Alexandros, of course, I didn't advocate giving PhD's "for effort". And, in fact, there is an ever-greater push at my university to have very limited time after "prelim oral exam" to finish the degree, apart from funding. It is a hostile situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to consider is that showing fault in an "established" result is, in itself, an important result. If a student spent years working on a project, only to find that the results from their new work disprove earlier accepted results, that's worth telling other researchers (i.e. publishable). Especially considering there's probably dozens of other graduate students all working off those same results until someone tells them the results are not reliable. In fact, my father, an emeritus professor of mathematics, lists "counter-examples" as one of his areas of research.

In the case of proofs and lemmas (i.e. case 1), this is clearly publishable. In the case of experiments, it's a little harder: you would need to make a strong case for your new experiment being substantial evidence that the previous results were wrong, rather than you just botched your experiment. But if you can make a solid case, it is well worth publishing.

Sadly, the third case is not so good for the student. Assuming the student's colleague has not published yet, the research community does not benefit much from the student saying "hey I just realized my friend messed up". They should still tell their colleague and advisor so that the situation is communicated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a problem at all. As a matter of fact, correcting previously published results and refining applied methods is part of research. Such an honest mistake is not an offence or ethnical misconduct in any way.